# How do I remove a node from the front page after a certain period of time?

Tags: rules

Can I use the Rules module to remove a node from the front page after a period of time determined by the administrator user when creating the node?

Comment: Welcome to DA! Honestly this question lacks a little bit of effort. Please tell us for example what have you tried so far? What exactly didn't work as expected?

Comment: I recently got an internship, and that's my first time learning about drupal, so I'm not that experienced, and I can't find any real documentation that get's close to my goal, my task is to remove a content from the front page after a certain amount of time, at first, I tried with normal scheduler, but then realized that I could not do this kind of tasks with it, so I got me studying Rules a little bit, but until now, I can't find a way to schedule my tasks, and I am really trying to get on this.

Comment: I am getting close to it, I added a new field in my article with the date module, and after this created a new Rule "Content viewed", with the condition date comparison "is lower than", but now I am wondering how can I select the date passed in the article's date field in my comparison

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module together with `Rules Scheduler` (a sub-module of it), as explained in the steps below. These steps are based on the assumption that your content type is `article` (adapt to whatever else fits).

#### Step 1: Create a field to store the expiration date

Add a field to the article content type (to store the "expiration" date), with these specs:

- Machine name (say) `field_expiration_date`.
- Use "date" as field type, for which the date module (and data API) needs to be enabled first.
- Allow only 1 date.

#### Step 2: Create a Rules Component

Here is the **Rules Component** to be created (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format, just import it in your own environment via copy-paste):

```
{ "rules_unpublish_a_node" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unpublish a node",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node_to_be_unpublished" : { "label" : "Node to be unpublished", "type" : "node" } },
    "DO" : [ { "node_unpublish" : { "node" : [ "node-to-be-unpublished" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

If you do not want the node to be unplublished, you can also replace the Rules Action by another one to just perform a "remove sticky" for the node.

#### Step 3: Create a Rule using the Rules Component

Here is the **Rule** to be created, in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format (just import it in your own environment via copy-paste, then "enable" the rule also):

```
{ "rules_schedule_the_unpublish_of_a_node_as_requested_by_author" : {
    "LABEL" : "Schedule the unpublish of a node as requested by author",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_expiration_date" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_unpublish_a_node",
          "date" : [ "node:field-expiration-date" ],
          "identifier" : "Unpublish-node-[node:nid]",
          "param_node_to_be_unpublished" : [ "node" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the above rule refers to the *Rules Component* from the previous step. Make sure to only perform the import of this rule only **after** you completed step 1, if not the import will fail ... Should you want to use another machine name, then change `field_expiration_date` in the rule above to what you prefer, prior to importing this rule.

**Be aware**: the above rule is only triggered once, i.e. when the node (of type article) is first created (as in the question). It will right away schedule the unpublish of the node (as requested in the expiration date). If the node gets edited later on, and/or the expiration date is changed afterwards: too bad, that won't change anything to when the scheduled unpublish is going to happen.